# Scrape "infomoney.com.br" with Selenium leads to ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some news titles and links from the website https://www.infomoney.com.br/ultimas-noticias/ but to load more news is needed to click in a Load More button ("Carregar Mais" in blue at the bottom of the news) but I always end getting the ElementClickInterceptedException error. I tried many different approaches but not worked. The base code is

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(jornal_infomoney)
time.sleep(40)

for _ in range(5):
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='infinite-handle']//button")
    button.click()
    #button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Carregar mais']")
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)
    #ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform()
    #button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Carregar mais']")))
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    '''
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Carregar mais']")))
    button.click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    load_more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Carregar mais']")))
    load_more_button.click().perform()
    '''
    time.sleep(2)

results_infomoney = pd.DataFrame(columns=['link', 'titulo', 'data', 'conteudo'])
article_id = 0

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
articles = soup.find_all("div", class_="row py-3 item")

for article in articles:
    article_title = article.find("span", class_="hl-title hl-title-2").find("a")
    article_link = article_title["href"]
    new_article = pd.DataFrame([{'link':article_link, 'titulo':article_title}])
    results_infomoney = pd.concat([results_infomoney, new_article], ignore_index = True)
    article_id+=1

driver.quit()

results_infomoney.to_excel((output_folder + '/results_infomoney_v1.xlsx'))
```

There is some pieces that are commented because I tried everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case contains 4 problems.

1. Google ads backdrop is blocking site area on load.
2. Cookies consent is appeared and intercepts the click (button to accept is placed in shadow-root)
3. Even after closing 1, 2 button is not in viewport, you need to scroll to it
4. After scrolling you need to wait for re-rendering

So, your steps are:

1. Wait for consent, go inside shadow-root and close it
2. Make google ads invisible, using JS
3. Get height of articles area and scroll by it's amount
4. Click on button and wait until it was re-rendered
5. Repeat

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

driver.get("https://www.infomoney.com.br/ultimas-noticias/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cookies-policy[class]")))
shadow_host = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', consent)
WebDriverWait(shadow_host, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'soma-button.primary'))).click()
driver.execute_script("""
const modal = document.querySelector('#OutOfPage'); 
if (modal) { 
   modal.style.display = 'none'; 
}
""")

for _ in range(5):
    load_more = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='infinite-handle']//button")))
    dates = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.item .hl-date')))
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', dates[-1])
    wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(load_more)
    load_more.click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(load_more))
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but the code scrolls for the right amount for the first and second loop, but in the third attempt, it scrolls past the button breaking the code, I again tried many things but I keep getting stuck

Comment: @CarlosEduardoBarros try updated snippet - this time it should work for you.